# database actions select , update , insert and delete

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How i can make a decision to use Linq or Entity Framework as  data access layer and business logic layer from performance
viewpoint (execution time ,  roundtrips ).

Comment: Not enough information to give you a good answer.

Comment: If only database operations were this simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single best answer, it depends on a lot of factors surrounding the particular app.

There really is no way to answer this without a lot more information.